# Setting cache folder does not work fat-free-framework

Tags: fat-free-framework

Im trying to put my cache folder but it does not working.
My code:

```
include_once '/var/www/libs/mainCache/fatfree-master/lib/base.php';

        $cache = \Cache::instance();
        $test = $cache->load(true, "folder=/var/www/soFitTest/cache/");
        var_dump($test);
```

The result:

```
string(17) "folder=tmp/cache/"
```

Why I cant set the cache folder?

Answer (score 0):

The call method should be called like this :

```
$test = $cache->load("folder=/var/www/soFitTest/cache/");
```

as  [mentioned on F3 documentation](http://fatfreeframework.com/cache#load)